# Flutter Dio send multipart form with Text and Image array to PHP file on backend

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, multipart, dio

I hope someone can help me.
I have a problem with my app, I can't send a form to my backend and save data to mysql database.
I use Dio with Flutter to send the form to my backend to a PHP file.
I can send multiple images as well as text, and so far it works fine. The problem is that, as I have written it now, a row is saved in the database for each image, i.e. if I load 1 image it creates a row in the database with the text I entered and the name of the image but if I upload 2 images, 2 rows are saved in the database instead of 1.

I would like a row to be saved in the database with the text fields that I send plus a JSON with the names of the images.

Here are some screenshots and the code I'm using now.
Please, if anyone knows how to help me don't hesitate, I've been banging on this thing for days.

Thank you

---

FLUTTER

```
Future postOperation(
  BuildContext context,
  String operationType,
  String operation,
  String description,
) async {
  try {
    var uuid = const Uuid();
    final user = await context.read<UserProvider>().getUser();
    final imageList = context.read<OperationProvider>().images;

    for (var image in imageList) {
      MultipartFile multipartFile = MultipartFile.fromFileSync(
        image.path,
        contentType: MediaType('image', image.path.split('.').last),
        filename: '${uuid.v1()}.${image.path.split('.').last}',
      );

      FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
        'user_id': user.userId!.trim(),
        'palace_id': user.palaceId!.trim(),
        'operation_type': operationType.trim(),
        'operation': operation.trim(),
        'description': description.trim(),
        "media": multipartFile,
      });

      var response = await Dio().post(
        AppConst.operation,
        data: formData,
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print('Operation uploaded - server response: ${response.statusCode}');
      } else {
        print(
            'Operation not uploaded - server response: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    print(error);
  }
}
```

---

PHP

```
<?php
require_once "../../conn/conn.php";

if ($_POST['user_id']) {
  $base = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']."://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
  $path = "/media/operation/";
  $domanin = "$base$path";

  $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['user_id']);
  $palace_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['palace_id']);
  $operation_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['operation_type']);
  $operation = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['operation']);
  $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['description']);

  $image[] = $_FILES['media']['name'];
  $tmpFile[] = $_FILES['media']['tmp_name'];

  foreach ($image as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($tmpFile as $key => $tmpFileValue) {
      move_uploaded_file($tmpFileValue, '../../media/operation/'.$value);
    }
  }

  $media = "$domanin$value";
  $encode = json_encode($media);

  $query = "
  INSERT INTO operation (palace_id, user_id, operation_type, operation, description, media)
  VALUES ('$palace_id', '$user_id', '$operation_type', '$operation', '$description', '$encode')
  ";
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

  mysqli_close($connect);
}
?>
```

---

DATABASE

[image]

---

[image]

---

I would like to get a result like this.
Practically on the Database I would like the "media" field to be an array of images.

```
[
   {
      "user_id":"1",
      "palace_id":"1",
      "operation_type":"Operation Type",
      "operation":"Operation",
      "description":"Description",
      "media":[
         "66b36250-7cf4-11ed-8311-e1017d35fc4f.jpg",
         "6g09e250-7cf4-1emd-8311-e1017cb3934f.jpg"
      ]
   },
   {
      "user_id":"1",
      "palace_id":"1",
      "operation_type":"Operation Type",
      "operation":"Operation",
      "description":"Description",
      "media":[
         "66b34950-7cf4-11ed-8151-e148gwk3fc4f.jpg",
         "649gen50-7cf4-11ed-8151-e148gwk3fc4f.jpg",
         "663of950-7cf4-11ed-8151-e148gwk3fc4f.jpg"
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: `for (var image in imageList)` - you are making one request per image in that loop ...

Comment: @CBroe  Do u know how can send 1 request and upload media field as an array of image in base of my PHP file?

Comment: Did you find any solution. If yes please post.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a list of file in the dio simply by making the field as list. Here is an example how you can do it

```
final multipartImageList =
    imageList.map((image) => MultipartFile.fromFileSync(image)).toList();

var formData = FormData.fromMap({
  'user_id': user.userId!.trim(),
  'palace_id': user.palaceId!.trim(),
  'operation_type': operationType.trim(),
  'operation': operation.trim(),
  'description': description.trim(),
  'media': multipartImageList
});
var response = await dio.post('/info', data: formData);
```

Comment: I have followed r comment: the fields are uploaded but inside media I have 1 single image url, I need that the field "media" in the database is an array of image urls